# Can Multiple different Servlets be run Sequentially in a java EE project?

Tags: java, html, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am having a html page, which takes in the username and password and takes it to the servlet for authenticating. If authenticated, it gets a link to go to another html page, which accepts input for placing a order, this inputs are finally passed to a servlet, which makes the data persistent by storing it in the database,

By far, i can make a html page for username and password and a servlet for authenticating. even the link for going to another html page, which accepts the input of the order details also works, after that, the servlet does not work.

Using Glasfish Server and netbeans for development.

Answer (score 0):

check [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) : they are invoked before/after a servlet, and are used to handle authentication, caching, etc